# Why does homebrew ask me to add --force option when linking keg-only formula?

Tags: node.js, homebrew

After running

```
brew install yarn
```

I have the below version of `node` installed on my system:

```
$ node -v
v10.5.0
```

because `node` is a dependency of `yarn` (correct me if I'm wrong, please tell me if I'm right too)

But it causes problem with `yarn` (the problem I face is [this](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5477)) so I want to use an older version of `node` to make my app work now. According to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171530/how-do-i-downgrade-node-or-install-a-specific-previous-version-using-homebrew), I did these:

```
$ brew install node@8
$ brew unlink node
$ brew link node@8
```

But `$ brew link node@8` gives me the following:

```
Warning: node@8 is keg-only and must be linked with --force
Note that doing so can interfere with building software.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

I used rvm, ruby can be switch by simply using `rvm use ruby-version-here` so I think `brew link formula` will work, but why it needs force?

I understand that brew's keg-only means it's only in cellar and not linked in /usr/local/bin/ or /usr/local/lib/, but isn't brew link helping us link it, why does it need the --force option, what does it do, it feels dangerous.

`brew help link` says:

> If --force (or -f) is passed, Homebrew will allow keg-only formulae to
>   be linked.

Why should we be careful to link them? Will we break something?

I want to use `node@8` instead of `node (the latest version)`, what is the correct way to do this? Do I just run with the force option as suggested by brew?

**Update 1:**
When I keep searching and finding out why, I saw [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/11811), but I don't understand it fully. It seems like it needs to delete some file when linking to new version of formula. But I thought linking will be just replacing the link somewhere, maybe just replace one file? Why create a specific --force option for linking to new keg-only formula? I suspect there is something special about keg-only formula's nature. Does anyone understand why?

**Note:**
[This](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11091) and [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Formula-Cookbook.md) explains what keg-only means

Answer (score 3):

First, yes `node` is a dependency of `yarn`, you can check it with:

```
brew deps yarn
```

Then the `--force` option is maybe not so well named but it does what is said in the man page:

> If --force (or -f) is passed, Homebrew will allow keg-only formulae to be linked.

This is just the way Homebrew works, there is no fear to have.

== EDIT

In previous version of [Homebrew the documentation](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/12898/commits/fbf28ef7a165586f724054428f29d71f6784e529#diff-a0bede59d26c1a9672ef3a1f31461808R194) was much clearer:

> If `--force` is passed, Homebrew will delete files which already exist in the prefix while linking.
>
> If `--dry-run` or `-n` is passed, Homebrew will list all files which would
>       be deleted by `brew link --force`, but will not actually link or delete
>       any files.

== EDIT (2)

Here is the [discussion](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/13349) that precedes the introduction of the `--force` parameter to allow linking keg-only formula. The reasons behind it is that installing keg-only formula system wide could interfere with other tools that expect some specific versions of standard programs.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and info about `brew deps` command! it is really useful! For the `--force`, I think there must be some reason homebrew dev implement such option, so I will wait for some further answer and elaboration.

Comment: In previous versions of Homebrew things was clearer. See my edit.

Comment: in `If --force is passed, Homebrew will delete files which already exist in the prefix while linking.` What does the word `prefix` mean here?
Never mind, found the answer here: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/what-does-prefix-mean-in-this-statement/787

Comment: In current version of homebrew, I think they rename --force to --overwrite, so the documentation you included in the answer is for `--overwrite`, not `--force`, type `brew help link` to see this

Comment: Thanks for the update, can you give an example how it could be a problem? What do you mean by expect some specific version of standard program? Do you mean they assume the latest version of the program installed equal to the version they specifically wants? Wouldn't that cause trouble if the program got updated at some point and the version expected no longer are the one they expected?